# Error en MySQL UPDATE a partir de SELECT1

Tags: mysql, select, update, group-by, sum

Tengo dos tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists aromas (
    aro_id INTEGER(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    aro_fab_id VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    aro_nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    aro_stock FLOAT,
    PRIMARY KEY (aro_id));

CREATE TABLE if not exists histaromas (
    his_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    his_aro_id INTEGER(4) NOT NULL,
    his_fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    his_movimiento FLOAT NOT NULL,
    his_motivo VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (his_id));

ALTER TABLE histaromas
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_aro_id
    FOREIGN KEY (his_aro_id) REFERENCES aromas(aro_id);
```

Quiero actualizar periódicamente el campo `aro_stock` de la tabla `aromas` con la suma de los registros `his_movimiento` correspondientes a cada `aro_id`.
Si realizo la siguiente consulta, arroja el resultado deseado:

```
SELECT 
    aro.aro_fab_id, 
    aro.aro_nombre,
SUM(his.his_movimiento) 
FROM  histaromas his 
INNER JOIN aromas aro ON his.his_aro_id=aro.aro_id
GROUP BY aro.aro_id;
```

Siendo esta la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al transformarlo en una sentencia UPDATE da un error:

```
UPDATE aromas
SET aro.aro_stock=
SELECT 
    SUM(his.his_movimiento)
    FROM  histaromas his 
    INNER JOIN aromas aro ON his.his_aro_id=aro.aro_id
    GROUP BY aro.aro_id;
```

La salida es:

> Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'SELECT    SUM(his.his_movimiento)     FROM  histaromas
> his   INNER JOIN aromas ar' at line 3

Por más que he revisado y cambiado cosas, no consigo que la sentencia UPDATE me funcione.

Comment: Tu problema tiene la solución que se aplica en este Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955988/mysql-select-inside-update

Answer (score 0):

Por si acaso no te apetece mucho traducir...

Realmente, no puedes actualizar una tabla seleccionando como valor de una columna sus propios datos, aunque hagas el sumatorio o los trates de cualquier otra forma. Si lo piensas es inconsistente porque estás actualizando los datos que al mismo tiempo estás seleccionando. La solución que te indica el enlace que te di anteriormente es que crees en el select una subselect que haga de tabla para seleccionar los datos, de tal manera que puedas tener ya los datos en memoria.

```
UPDATE aromas
SET aro.aro_stock=
(SELECT 
    SUM(his.his_movimiento)
    FROM  histaromas his 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM aromas) AS aro ON his.his_aro_id=aro.aro_id
    GROUP BY aro.aro_id);
```

Prueba algo como eso a ver si funciona.

También puede ser que te comieras los paréntesis.

Comment: He realizado la siguiente consulta: `UPDATE aromas aro
SET aro.aro_stock=
(SELECT stock FROM
 (SELECT 
    SUM(his.his_movimiento) AS stock
    FROM  histaromas his 
    INNER JOIN aromas ON his.his_aro_id=aro.aro_id
    GROUP BY aro.aro_id)
  AS temp);` Ahora no da errores, pero el resultado es que me actualiza cada valor de la columna con la suma solicitada PERO multiplicada por el número de elementos de la tabla `aromas`. O sea, si la suma de movimientos de un aroma es 10 y hay 19 elementos en la tabla `aromas` la suma que me coloca en la casilla es 190.